# JTabbedPane Scroll Button Position

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

Been working with `JTabbedPane` and trying to customize it when using `SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT` specifically with the scroll direction buttons.

I'm extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, but I don't see a method or ability to change the location of the scroll buttons. Searched around and don't see any one doing this other than just using different look and feels. Control over the location of scroll direction buttons would be very useful in general I feel.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this while extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI` or any other method?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to move the scroll backwards button to the other side of the tabs.

In the [BasicTabbedPaneUI](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI-source.html) class, there's a `createDecreaseButton` method that's package only (no access modifier).

It appears you're going to have to create your own `BasicTabbedPaneUI` class, with your own version of `createDecreaseButton`.

Comment: agreed to hard modifying these two buttons +1

Comment: Thanks for that. Basically what I had feared :) Ended up basically implementing my own tab pane, using various components. Overode the BasicTabbedPaneUI paint methods to eliminate the builtin tabs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the scroll button position without using many other components but simply extends the BasicTabbedPaneUI and hacking its paint() method to adjust the button position.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyTabbedScrollPane extends JTabbedPane {       
    public MyTabbedScrollPane ()
    {
        super ();
    }

    public MyTabbedScrollPane ( final int tabPlacement )
    {
        super ( tabPlacement );
    }

    public MyTabbedScrollPane ( final int tabPlacement, final int tabLayoutPolicy )
    {
        super ( tabPlacement, tabLayoutPolicy );
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        setUI(new MyTabbedPaneUI());
    }

    private class MyTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {
        private int leadingTabIndex;
        private Point tabViewPosition;
        private Component adjustedButton;
        private boolean scrollableTabLayoutEnabled() {
            return tabPane.getTabLayoutPolicy() == SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT;
        }
        /*
         * Target button and view port utilities
         */
        private Component findBackwardButton() {
            Component[] comps = tabPane.getComponents();
            for(Component comp:comps) {
                if(comp instanceof BasicArrowButton) {
                    int direction = ((BasicArrowButton)comp).getDirection();
                    if(tabPane.getTabPlacement() == TOP || tabPane.getTabPlacement() == BOTTOM) {
                        if(direction == WEST) {
                            return comp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        private JViewport findViewPort() {
            Component[] comps = tabPane.getComponents();
            for(Component comp:comps) {
                if(comp instanceof JViewport) {
                    return (JViewport)comp;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        /*
         * Override View port controlling (copy from BasicTabbedPaneUI.java)
         */
        public void scrollForward(int tabPlacement) {
            JViewport viewport = findViewPort();
            Dimension viewSize = viewport.getViewSize();
            Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();

            if (tabPlacement == TOP || tabPlacement == BOTTOM) {
                if (viewRect.width >= viewSize.width - viewRect.x) {
                    return; // no room left to scroll
                }
            } else { // tabPlacement == LEFT || tabPlacement == RIGHT
                if (viewRect.height >= viewSize.height - viewRect.y) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            setLeadingTabIndex(tabPlacement, leadingTabIndex+1);
        }

        public void scrollBackward(int tabPlacement) {
            if (leadingTabIndex == 0) {
                return; // no room left to scroll
            }
            setLeadingTabIndex(tabPlacement, leadingTabIndex-1);
        }

        public void setLeadingTabIndex(int tabPlacement, int index) {
            JViewport viewport = findViewPort();
            leadingTabIndex = index;       
            Dimension viewSize = viewport.getViewSize();
            Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();

            int offsetX = adjustedButton.getWidth()+2;

            switch(tabPlacement) {
              case TOP:
              case BOTTOM:
                tabViewPosition.x = leadingTabIndex == 0? 0-offsetX : rects[leadingTabIndex].x-offsetX;

                if ((viewSize.width - tabViewPosition.x) < viewRect.width) {
                    // We've scrolled to the end, so adjust the viewport size
                    // to ensure the view position remains aligned on a tab boundary
                    Dimension extentSize = new Dimension(viewSize.width - tabViewPosition.x, 
                                                         viewRect.height);
                    viewport.setExtentSize(extentSize);
                }
                break;
              case LEFT:
              case RIGHT:
                tabViewPosition.y = leadingTabIndex == 0? 0 : rects[leadingTabIndex].y;

                if ((viewSize.height - tabViewPosition.y) < viewRect.height) {
                // We've scrolled to the end, so adjust the viewport size
                // to ensure the view position remains aligned on a tab boundary
                     Dimension extentSize = new Dimension(viewRect.width, 
                                                          viewSize.height - tabViewPosition.y);
                     viewport.setExtentSize(extentSize);
                }
            }
            viewport.setViewPosition(tabViewPosition);
        }
        /*
         * UI Rendering
         */
        public void paint(final Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            super.paint(g, c);
            if(scrollableTabLayoutEnabled()) {
                if(adjustedButton == null) {
                    adjustedButton = findBackwardButton();
                    tabViewPosition = new Point(0-(adjustedButton.getWidth()+2), 0);
                    Component[] comps = tabPane.getComponents();
                    for(Component comp:comps) {
                        if(comp instanceof BasicArrowButton) {
                            if(comp instanceof BasicArrowButton) {
                                BasicArrowButton button = (BasicArrowButton)comp;
                                int direction = button.getDirection();
                                if(tabPane.getTabPlacement() == TOP || tabPane.getTabPlacement() == BOTTOM) {
                                    // left align the west button
                                    if(direction == WEST) {
                                        button.removeActionListener(button.getActionListeners()[0]);
                                        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                                         
                                            @Override
                                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                                scrollBackward(tabPane.getTabPlacement());
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else if(direction == EAST) {
                                        button.removeActionListener(button.getActionListeners()[0]);
                                        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                                         
                                            @Override
                                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                                scrollForward(tabPane.getTabPlacement());
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(adjustedButton != null && adjustedButton.isVisible()) {
                    // move the scroll button
                    int by = adjustedButton.getY();
                    adjustedButton.setLocation(0, by);
                    findViewPort().setViewPosition(tabViewPosition);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```